# Binomial Coefficient as Sum of a Sum

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Few days ago, I found this equation:

$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j>i} \frac{1}{2} = {n \choose 2} \frac{1}{2} 
$

I didn't manage to prove it. 
Does anyone of you know how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j>i} \frac{1}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i) \frac{1}{2} = \big(n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\big)\frac{1}{2} 
 = {n \choose 2} \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: how did you get from (1) to (2)?

[1] $(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-n)$

[2] $(n^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2})$

Comment: now it's written properly.

Comment: @user1384636 group $n$ together, you get $n^2$, and $(1+2+\cdots +n)=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$

Comment: yes! 
I'm starting to lose my mind